# Extra verbose python debugger

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.5, pdb

I am having a hard time figuring out an apparently random halting problem of a complex script.

I would love to have an extra verbose debugger tool that would print which line is being processed while the program executes. Is there anything like that? Can pdb do this?

Thank you.

Comment: Make your choice: https://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonDebuggingTools

Comment: all of those do that? How to do it in pdb?

Comment: Does it crashes?

Comment: it doesnt. It 'randomly' halts, sometimes it takes hours to halt... i cant just use 'next' on pdb

Comment: Pdb has a postmortem, it helped me some times

Comment: it needs to crash to be used, right? ):

Comment: Usually on this situations I do a conditional break, do you have an idea where in code is hanging? Is it multithread?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/190429/discussion-between-lucas-azevedo-and-geckos).

Comment: You can distribute prints in the code to find out where is hanging. Then you put set_trace() inside if statements that you think that is true only during the hang. Once you get a breakpoint hit you want to get a stacktrace and inspect the variables

Comment: thats exactly why I wanted a debugger, not to flood the code with prints all over it.